# Suggested way to use the qsort function

Tags: c, qsort

Is it more common to use casts every time values are compared or to start by defining the types explicitly at the top of the function. For example:

```
int comp1(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const int *v1 = p1;
    const int *v2 = p2;
    if (*v1 == *v2)
        return 0;
    else if (*v1 > *v2)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Or doing the casts implicitly:

```
int comp2(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    if (*(int*)p1 == *(int*)p2)
        return 0;
    else if (*(int*)p1 > *(int*)p2)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Or I suppose even doing:

```
int comp3(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return (*(int*)p1 > *(int*)p2 ? 1 : (*(int*)p1==*(int*)p2)? 0 : -1);
}
```

Why would one for be preferred over another?

Comment: The first is more common because it's more readable.

Comment: Can you provide any good reason to use the totally incomprehensible last version? Don't say performance, because any decent compiler will produce nearly identical code for all 3 versions.

Comment: For integers (or other numeric types), you should probably use `int comp_int(const void *p1, const void *p2) { int v1 = *(int *)p1; int v2 = *(int *)p2; if (v1 == v2) return 0; else if (v1 > v2) return 1; else return -1; }` or even this, which may avoid branching/conditionals: `int comp_int(const void *p1, const void *p2) { int v1 = *(int *)p1; int v2 = *(int *)p2; return (v1 > v2) - (v1 < v2); }`.  However, there's a decent chance the compiler will optimize the pointer references in `comp1()` from the question to be equivalent to the first `comp_int()` shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Code for clarity, 99.99% of the time over something that might look *faster*.  Trust your compiler or use a better one.
2. Generally, avoid casting.

Many compilers will emit efficient code with the following idiom.

```
int comp4(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
  const int *v1 = p1;
  const int *v2 = p2;
  return (*v1 > *v2) - (*v1 < *v2);
}
```